# JavaScript button next and prev

Tags: javascript

I have made an image gallery but then decided to add buttons Previous and Next so it will show Previous and Next Image but it doesn't work and have been loking where's the problem but cannot find the problem, because Console.Log doesn't show any errors too.
Can anyone take a look at the code below and try to solve it ? Thanks
:::

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

let modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');

let prevBtn = document.querySelector('.img-left');

let nextBtn = document.querySelector('.img-right');

let i = 0;

window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

prevBtn.onclick = function () {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
    i = slide.length - 1;
    }
    slide[i].classList.add('active');
}
nextBtn.onclick = function () {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
    i++;
    if(i >= slide.length) {
    i = 0;
    }
    slide[i].classList.add('active');
}

function outsideClick(e) {
    if(e.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    let img = images[i];
    img.onclick = function(e) {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        modalImg.src = this.src;
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 370px;
}
.grids2{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grids3{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2/1;
}
.grids4{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grids5{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
img{
    width: 410px;
    height: 290px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 150px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
  }
  
  .animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    color:red;
  }
.img-right{
  position: absolute;
  left: 72%;
  top: 36%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  font-size: 48px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 96px;
  height: 90px;
}
.img-left{
  position: absolute;
  right: 72%;
  top: 36%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 96px;
  height: 90px;
}
.img-left:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
.img-right:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
/*End of Slideshow*/
```

```html
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="grid2s">
                      <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg">
                     </div>
                   <div class="grids3">
                      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tinycards/image/009ffb0bab62af8a498d2493c1dfd927">
                     </div>
                   <div class="grids4">
                      <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/childrens-responsive-ichef-live/r/880/1x/cbbc/Animaltastic_Ambigous_Animals_Names_1024_576.jpg">
                     </div>
                     <div class="grids5">
                         <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/976x549/p04f5x5v.jpg">
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal">
                    <img class="modal-content animated fadeIn" id="img01">
                    <img class="img-left" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/467/467282.svg">
                    <img class="img-right" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/467/467274.svg">
                  </div>
```

Comment: The modal isn't properly scaled to the screen, I can't see the buttons in either Stack overflow or codepen

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz.comfor the same, if you want you can use some ready made carousel build in jquery / javascript like http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Done have fixed the code and its showing buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
// Don't include arrows in array of pictures for slider !
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.container img');
```

Then... the `slide` array you use in click function is not defined. I think `images` and `slide` var should be the same.

And then, all is working as expected: the `.active` class jump over each image each time prev or next button is clicked.

At last, you just require to update modal content, like:

```js
modalImg.src = slide[i].src;
```

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.container img');
let modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
let prevBtn = document.querySelector('.img-left');
let nextBtn = document.querySelector('.img-right');

let i = 0;

window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

prevBtn.onclick = function () {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
    i = slide.length - 1;
    }
    modalImg.src = slide[i].src;
    slide[i].classList.add('active');
}
nextBtn.onclick = function () {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
    i++;
    if(i >= slide.length) {
    i = 0;
    }
    modalImg.src = slide[i].src;
    slide[i].classList.add('active');
}

function outsideClick(e) {
    if(e.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    let img = slide[i];
    img.onclick = function(e) {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        modalImg.src = this.src;
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 370px;
}
.grids2{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grids3{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2/1;
}
.grids4{
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grids5{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
img{
    width: 410px;
    height: 290px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 150px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
  }
  
  .animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    color:red;
  }
.img-right{
  position: absolute;
  left: 72%;
  top: 36%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  font-size: 48px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 96px;
  height: 90px;
}
.img-left{
  position: absolute;
  right: 72%;
  top: 36%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 96px;
  height: 90px;
}
.img-left:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
.img-right:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
/*End of Slideshow*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
                   <div class="grid2s">
                      <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg">
                     </div>
                   <div class="grids3">
                      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tinycards/image/009ffb0bab62af8a498d2493c1dfd927">
                     </div>
                   <div class="grids4">
                      <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/childrens-responsive-ichef-live/r/880/1x/cbbc/Animaltastic_Ambigous_Animals_Names_1024_576.jpg">
                     </div>
                     <div class="grids5">
                         <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/976x549/p04f5x5v.jpg">
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal">
                    <img class="modal-content animated fadeIn" id="img01">
                    <img class="img-left" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/467/467282.svg">
                    <img class="img-right" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/467/467274.svg">
                  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I still ran into a problem when tried to change as you said and it doesn't work for me ?
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/zeZxbX

Comment: Nevermind man, it works now as I updated images.length to slide.length as you said to change let images to let slide and forgot to change some lines below let.
Thanks for your help man ;)

Comment: As an example for learning, take a look at [this jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/mab/muLrkzw9/3/). The HTML & CSS are the same as yours, and the JS is much like yours, but with some improvements and a different way of coding.

Comment: I used this code you made but there's an delay when it comes to the last image so I have to click 2 times to show next image from beginning any idea why this happening because tried Chrome and Firefox but there's still a delay when it slides ?

Comment: I may have made a mistake on the way to compute `nextIndex`. I did not spend a lot of time to check everything, but feel free to investigate ;)
*(I may take a look later at this weird behavior… but don't know when)*

Comment: no your code on Jsfiddle it slides without no delay but in my computer I have the same code but there's some type of delay and had another slider that i made and there's not delay, so i have to look at the code it could be any issue, thanks again man :)